# Looping over 16 numbers, but excluding one each time

Tags: r, loops, math

Using expression the following expression I want to compute the influence of each data point in the an election forecast data set (see bottom). My idea is to loop through the expression 16 times and print the result, but for each time I loop through leave on x_1 out to see how each of them influences the result. But I have no idea how to make this loop in R.

The expression is:
LaTeX
`$$ \hat{b} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} ({x_i}-{\bar{x}){y_i}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} ({x_i}-{\bar{x})}^2} $$`

And in R

```
betahat<- (sum(data$growth)-mean(data$growth))*data$vote/(sum(data$growth)-mean(data$growth))^2
print(betahat)
```

And the data is this
`data <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avehtari/ROS-Examples/master/ElectionsEconomy/data/hibbs.dat", header = TRUE)`

Expected functioning:

```
0   1    2                 0   x    x                0   1    2
1   2    4    first loop   1   2    4   second loop  1   x    x   etc.
2   3    6       --->      2   3    6     --->       2   3    6   --->
3   4    8                 3   4    8                3   4    8
4   5   10                 4   5   10                4   5   10
```

The first output should be something like

```
 [1] 1.566974 2.029337 1.753535 2.155116 1.742644 2.170927 1.719807 1.570487 2.078876
[10] 1.895125 1.635485 1.923232 1.766184 1.800264 1.627404 1.826965
```

Comment: Can you provide expected output for first few rows?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: I don't see how `data` and expected functioning or output is related.